# Quicker way to validate ranges in conditional statements?

Tags: java, integer, conditional-statements

I'm currently working on something (for practice, I'm a beginner) that requires a lot of integer ranges. Now it was basically common sense to just do it this way:

```
else if (age >= 2 && age <=3){
    System.out.println("You're a toddler!");
```

however, I feel like there must be a faster way to create ranges for conditional statements, I just can't imagine this is the fastest way to do it. If there isn't, that's okay. I just don't want to keep doing it this way if there is a faster way. Thanks.

Comment: If these are concatenated ranges that map all discrete values you can use a single comparison. (`age<2`, `age<=3` ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're mapping values that cover an entire range you can use a single comparison by controlling their order and return a value from a function as means to skip later comparisons:

```
public String ageDescription(short age){
    if (age < 2){
        return "less than 2";
    }

    if (age <= 3){
        // we know age >= 2 since we didn't return
        return "more than 2 but less than or equal to 3";
    }
    // no comparison for last value
    return "You're older than 3";
}
```

However, the way you're doing it at the moment is perfectly fine.

Comment: I assume I have a negative score because someone probably thinks this is a bad idea or does not understand it. Either way we can not know if he does not leave a comment.

Comment: shouldn't the second statement be "else if"? Because if they are both if then it could return both, but if you do else if it will only do the correct one.

Comment: A function returns **one** reference and does it **immediately**.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The downvote is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for this, for example:

```
public class Range{
    int min;
    int max;
    String msg;
    public Range(int min, int max, String msg){
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    public boolean isInRange(int val){
        return val >= min && val <= max;
    }

    public void showMessage(){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

and this is how you can use it:

```
Range range1 = new Range(2,3,"You're a toddler!");
Range range2 = new Range(4,8,"....");
Range range3 = new Range(9,12,"....");
List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(range1,range2,range3));
int val = ...;
for(Range range:ranges){
    if(range.isInRange(val)){
        range.showMessage();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this make it easier but it definitely makes it more dynamic, it makes it easier to add/remove ranges at runtime.